# Going back to Montreal with expired passport

Tags: air-travel, passports

I am a French national living in Quebec, Canada. I am a Canadian permanent resident.
I'm currently in Mexico and need to get back to Montreal.

My French passport expired 2 weeks ago.
What are my options?
Can I board a direct flight (Air Transat) from Cancun to Montreal (YUL) with this passport and my permanent resident card?

Comment: I doubt this would be possible, but as there may be exceptions I'm not aware of I'm not making this an answer. If, as I think, it's not possible, your best bet is to get a new passport from the French embassy in Mexico City. If you qualify for it you may get an emergency passport. Otherwise the wait is quite long apparently (no appointments available at this time).

Answer (score 2):

> My French passport expired 2 weeks ago.

Huge mistake, as you are about to find out.

Contact the Canadian embassy in Mexico City or any of the numerous consulates. They *might* give you a travel authorization. They have no obligation to do so, but it's Canada, eh.

You DO have a valid Permanent Resident card, yes? Gets much harder without one.

If Canada says the travel authorizations are only for citizens, then your only reasonable* option is the French Embassy in Mexico city, conveniently a 20 minute walk from the Canadians. Also talk to your hotel about extending your stay until your passport arrives.

Come back and tell us what worked (and what didn't work).

* You could take a boat through the Caribbean, stay more than 12 miles from US coasts, and land at St. Pierre et Miquelon. Then it's a ferry to Newfoundland. Your French citizenship gets you onto St. Pierre, your PR card gets you back into Canada. I can't imagine this costing less than staying in Mexico for upwards of a year or two.

Comment: Then there is the question if the Mexican visa is still valid...

Comment: Canada issues certificate of identity for its permanent residents only if they cannot obtain a travel document from their country of citizenship or protection or cannot do so within a reasonable time and have an urgent need to travel.

Comment: @xngtng "le queue de passport being over a year" and "do not want to do time in a Mexican prison for overstaying" would seem to cover it.

Comment: @John I would expect that they would want to see if the French consulate consider not overstaying an acceptable reason for a French urgent passport or laissez-passer first.

Comment: @xngtng the embassies are 20 minutes apart, so he can easily do he said / she said between them and see what shakes out the easiest.

Comment: @John, If he's a visitor to Mexico he may have already overstayed since FMM stays are supposed to be limited by passport validity (that's assuming the immigration officer noticed). Overstays typically aren't punished with jail in Mexico, though there would be a fine to pay if the airline notices (there is no exit formalities for visitors beyond giving the FMM stub to the airline).

Comment: @Dennis at no point has Mexico Mike mentioned his status in Mexico, so lets file that in the "not our problem" box.